# SQLite DUVIDA BASIC A

Tags: sqlite

Galera estou aprendendo sqlite e aprendi a fazer o crud tendo duvida se quando eu acabar de fazer o apk e colocar no celular ele vai criar sozinho o arquivo do banco e vai criar e vasculhar ou eu tenho que criar manualmente o arquivo 
?

Answer (score 0):

Obviamente seu aplicativo tem que ser capaz de criar e manipular o banco de dados por si só, não é? Já pensou se seu usuário tivesse que sair criando banco por aí?

Por exemplo, o método abaixo abre ou cria um banco de dados caso ele não exista ainda e deve estar em algum lugar do seu aplicativo:

```
SQLiteDatabase meuBanco = this.openOrCreateDatabase("nomeDoBanco", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
```